# How to use a variable in a match method with regular expression pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I want to get an array in JavaScript from a string, cutting it in half.

Example:

```
// From this: 
   var myStr = 'cocacola';

// To this: 
   var myArray = ['coca', 'cola'];
```

I tried the following method:

```
var myStr = 'cocacola';
var strHalf = myStr.length / 2;
// This won't work
var myArray = myStr.match(/.{1,strHalf}/g);
// Only this will work fine
var myArray = myStr.match(/.{1,4}/g);
```

Comment: Why do you need regex for that ? Take a look at [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do String.slice() to solve this

```js
var myStr = 'cocacola';

let len = myStr.length;

let result = [myStr.slice(0, len/2), myStr.slice(len/2)]
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to to use the `RegExp()` constructor and make a string that it understands:

```
var regexString = "/.{1," + strHalf + "}/g";
var myRegex = new RegExp( regexString );
var myArray = myStr.match( myRegex );
```

...but be careful doing this; if `strHalf` is a string containing special characters like `/` then your RegExp will have weird behaviour.

Comment: @poster You do not "need to" use a regexp, but it is a viable option, indeed.

Comment: Yeah, based on the question title I figured that this was a technique that @Gabriel might want to use elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a non-hardcoded regexp by using the RegExp constructor:

```
var myArray = myStr.match(new RegExp('/.{1,'+strHalf+'}/g'));
```

The constructor has no clue that `strHalf` should be an integer, so make sure you can control that.

This is known to introduce a lot of security issues, please don't use this in production. Regexes are too often used when they shouldn't. If you ever use a regex, do look into other options

There are much better alternatives, but at least it's possible!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need regex for that.

The easiest way is that:

```
var myStr = 'cocacola';
var strHalf = myStr.length / 2;
var array = [myStr.substr(0, strHalf),myStr.substr(strHalf, myStr.length)];
```

**jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/cudg8qc3/

Answer (score 0):

You can just `slice` the string and place the first element in the first slot, and the second element in the second slot in the array.

```
var str_len = myStr.length
var my_array = [myStr.slice(0, str_len/2), myStr.slice(str_len/2, str_len)]
```